# A question on the Grammian matrix of a frame

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}=\left\{x_j\right\}_{j=1}^m$ be a frame in a Hilbert space of dimension $N$. Let $S$ its frame operator; it is represented by a Hermitian matrix denoted, with some abuse of notation, by $S$.

Let $u=u(\vec{c})=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x_j$.

I would like to calculate $\|S u\|^2$:
$$
\|S u\|^2=\left\langle\sum_j c_j \sum_k\left\langle x_j, x_k\right\rangle x_k, \sum_j c_j \sum_k\left\langle x_j, x_k\right\rangle x_k\right\rangle=\sum_{j, j^{\prime}} c_j c_{j^{\prime}} \sum_{k, k^{\prime}}\left\langle x_j, x_k\right\rangle\left\langle x_{j^{\prime}}, x_{k^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left\langle x_k, x_{k^{\prime}}\right\rangle
$$
I was thinking to semplify the above expression by using the Grammian matrix of the frame.

Let $G=\left\{\left\langle x_j, x_k\right\rangle\right\}_{j, k=1}^m$ be the Grammian matrix of the frame. Is the following true?
$$
\sum_{j, j^{\prime}} c_j c_{j^{\prime}} \sum_{k, k^{\prime}}\left\langle x_j, x_k\right\rangle\left\langle x_{j^{\prime}}, x_{k^{\prime}}\right\rangle\left\langle x_k, x_{k^{\prime}}\right\rangle=\left\langle G^3 \vec{c}, \vec{c}\right\rangle
$$